# Google Colab Latex format output

Tags: python, latex, google-colaboratory

Is there a way to output python strings in Latex format using google's Colab?

I mean something like this:

The command `print("$x^2$)"` would result with the output `$x^2$` (graphically, mathjax doesn't work here for some reason) and not `x^2`, similar to what `pyplot` offers.

Answer (score 3):

There is a built-in [snippet](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/advanced_outputs.ipynb#scrollTo=9G8w79zS5vG4) that shows how to render equations with SymPy and MathJax. In your Colab's notebook you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and then filter for "Rendering SymPy in Colab".

```py
from IPython.display import Math, HTML

def load_mathjax_in_cell_output():
  display(HTML("<script src='https://www.gstatic.com/external_hosted/"
               "mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=default'></script>"))
get_ipython().events.register('pre_run_cell', load_mathjax_in_cell_output)
```

After running this you can render cell with `%%latex` cell magic:

```py
%%latex
$$x^2$$
```

---

**Update:** After running the snippet you can render equations with previously imported `Math`. This will work for the entire notebook:

```py
output = 'x^2'
Math(output)
```

Comment: How do I use general string this way? For example, if I fon't know in advance that I want to print $x^2$, but some string that is returned from a function.

Comment: Is there away to have the magic apply for the entire notebook?

Comment: @proton I updated the answer. Let me know if this helps you.